# C++ Win32 notification menu changes

Tags: c++, winapi

I have two issues, which may have the same solution, if not I'll split it.

My notification tray icon and menu work well. I can respond to a click and open a window or perform an action.

I'm just trying to interact(change) with the menu itself. I'm using Visual Studio 2019, Win32 API (not MFC) and a resource for a menu.

1. How can I change text in a menu? (example, initial display "Start Action", once clicked change to "Stop Action")
2. How can I add / change an icon next to the text? (example, "Start Action" has bitmap1, "Stop Action" as bitmap2)

Everything is in classes, so I've just included the relevant menu code.

constructor:

```
hmenu = LoadMenu(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));
menuTrackPopup = GetSubMenu(hmenu, 0);
```

WndProc:

```
case WM_RBUTTONUP:
{
    POINT pCursor;
    GetCursorPos(&pCursor);

    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    TrackPopupMenu(hmenuTrackPopup, TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN, pCursor.x, pCursor.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);
}
```

I've tried different things like `SetMenuItemBitmaps` and `MenuItemInfo` and others but hopefully I'm just loading it wrong.

**-- EDIT--**

Due to frustrations in answers quoting references to MSDN, with no other explanation or backup code, and still getting up votes, I'm going to pad my questions with the references people post after I have stated I have tried it.

I would have though an answer on how to change the text or icon on a context menu be easy, it's a common feature on any windows application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuitembitmaps

```
BOOL SetMenuItemBitmaps(
    HMENU   hMenu,
    UINT    uPosition,
    UINT    uFlags,
    HBITMAP hBitmapUnchecked,
    HBITMAP hBitmapChecked
);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuiteminfow

```
BOOL SetMenuItemInfoW(
    HMENU            hmenu,
    UINT             item,
    BOOL             fByPositon,
    LPCMENUITEMINFOW lpmii
);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-menuiteminfow

```
typedef struct tagMENUITEMINFOW {
    UINT      cbSize;
    UINT      fMask;
    UINT      fType;
    UINT      fState;
    UINT      wID;
    HMENU     hSubMenu;
    HBITMAP   hbmpChecked;
    HBITMAP   hbmpUnchecked;
    ULONG_PTR dwItemData;
    LPWSTR    dwTypeData;
    UINT      cch;
    HBITMAP   hbmpItem;
} MENUITEMINFOW, *LPMENUITEMINFOW;
```

Comment: Note that this is not `c++` question and nothing connected to `c++17`. Win32 is pure C API.

Comment: I accept that, but that is what I'm using, I guess I could have mentioned that and not tagged it.

Comment: @i486 Win32 is not a pure C API, there are lots of C++/C++17 elements.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Win32 works on compilers from 1993. Where are C++17 elements, give one example? Also there are no classes and objects - if there is something incompatible with pure C, it is little exception. Most functions and structures are C-compatible.